# Show div out of window like html select box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to produce custom drop down with option that contains image and text.

In HTML select option it is only possible to put text.

All the existing custom drop downs (like bootsrap, jquery ui etc) creates DIVs that are shown like select, but if options height exceed window height we don't see all options.

That means i want to see it like select box which its options are shown overflown the window.

In other words, I am looking for a solution on how to make a div to be shown overflowing the window.

`For example:`

If DIV height is 400px and WINDOW is 300px the whole DIV is still shown (when part of div is out of window).

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: You need to add code to help out the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Try ddSlick jquery plugin. You can set a height which the drop down will then overflow. Here is a code sample of it working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDropdown"></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            //Dropdown plugin data
            var ddData = [{
                text: "Facebook",
                value: 1,
                selected: false,
                description: "Description with Facebook",
                imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            }, {
                text: "Twitter",
                value: 2,
                selected: false,
                description: "Description with Twitter",
                imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            }, {
                text: "LinkedIn",
                value: 3,
                selected: true,
                description: "Description with LinkedIn",
                imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            }, {
                text: "Foursquare",
                value: 4,
                selected: false,
                description: "Description with Foursquare",
                imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            }];

            $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
                data: ddData,
                width: 300,
                height: 110,
                selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
                imagePosition: "left",
                onSelected: function(selectedData) {}
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You will notice that the scrollbar appears for the drop down options with the height set.

You can test it [here](http://jsbin.com/rageguhuse/edit?html,js,output) on jsbin.

Comment: The options are steel not shown out of window scroll is shown